# Symfony 2 form repeated validation in Entity with annotation

Tags: symfony

My question is "How can I do form repeated validation in Entity with annotation?". I have an Account entity with (email, password and confirmPassword) attributes. When a new user registers a new account, he/she has to fill in email, password and confirmPassword fields. Obviously, password and confirmPassword fields must match. I saw an example of this validation with pure php (form builder) in Stachoverflow like below.

```
$builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
    'type' => 'password',
    'first_name' => 'Password',
    'second_name' => 'Password confirmation',
    'invalid_message' => 'Passwords are not the same',
));
```

But, this is not what I want. I want this functionality with annotation in my Account entity. Maybe

```
* @Assert\Match(
*      matchField = "password",
*      message = "The password confirmation does not match password."
* )
protected $confirmPassword;
```

Comment: Why would you use $confirmPassword in your entity?

Answer (score 2):

You might use method validation:

```
/**
 * @Assert\True(message = "Passwords are not the same")
 */
public function isPasswordLegal()
{
   return ($this->password == $this->confirmPassword);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html#validation

> One of the key features of the repeated field is internal validation
>   (you don't need to do anything to set this up) that forces the two
>   fields to have a matching value. If the two fields don't match, an
>   error will be shown to the user.